# Как в Select2 сделать задержку перед первой загрузкой данных?

Tags: ajax, select2

Для создания выпадающих списков пользуюсь jQuery плагином [select2](https://select2.org).

Значения для списка получаю с помощью `ajax`:

```
$('.parameters').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/ajax/parameters',
    delay: 500,
    data: function (params) { ... };
    processResults: function(data, params) { ... }
});
```

Необходимо установить задержку перед **первой** загрузкой данных. `delay` не справляется - по клику на выпадающий список моментально отправляется ajax-запрос на сервер, а если посетитель начинает вводить символы в строку поиска - формируется второй запрос уже с задержкой, указанной в `delay: 500`.

`minimumInputLength` не подходит, так как пользователь может ничего не ввести.

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function () {

        }, 2000);
```

Comment: это куда, в `ajax: { query: function() {} }` ?

Comment: @toxxa Можно попробовать в $('.parameters').select2({ 
});
 ajax: {
    url: '/ajax/parameters',
    delay: 500,
    data: function (params) { ... };
    processResults: function(data, params) { ... }
});

Comment: и все равно не понял, куда вы предлагаете вписать таймер? может в ajax-событие beforeSend? или setTimeout - это свойство объекта ajax?

Comment: @toxxxa это не свойство ajax, просто можно задержать выполнение функции